# NullPointerException when making XMPP connection through Smack 4.2.0

Tags: java, smack

I intend to use Smack to send messages through Firebase CCS. I modified a simple CCS client for my Web App but when I try to make connection, it results in exception.
I am using **Smack 4.2.0**

Here is the process of connection.

1) The connection method which is in my client:

```
public void connect() throws XMPPException{
        try{
            config = XMPPTCPConnectionConfiguration.builder()
                    .setPort(Config.FCM_PORT)
                    .setHost("fcm-xmpp.googleapis.com")
                    .setXmppDomain("googleapis.com")
                    .setSecurityMode(/*Default; Explicit setting for emphasis*/SecurityMode.ifpossible)
                    .setSendPresence(true)
                    .setUsernameAndPassword(fcmServerUsername, mApiKey)
                    .setSocketFactory(SSLSocketFactory.getDefault())
                    .setDebuggerEnabled(mDebuggable)/* Launch a window with info about packets sent and received */
                    .build();
        }
        catch(XmppStringprepException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        connection = new XMPPTCPConnection(config);


        // Configuring Automatic reconnection
        ReconnectionManager manager = ReconnectionManager.getInstanceFor(connection);
        manager.setReconnectionPolicy(ReconnectionManager.ReconnectionPolicy.RANDOM_INCREASING_DELAY);
        manager.enableAutomaticReconnection();

        // Connect now then login
        try{
            connection.connect();
            connection.login();
        }
        // TODO: Handle the exceptions if possible appropriately
        catch(SmackException sme){
            logger.severe(sme.getMessage());
            sme.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(IOException ioe){
            logger.severe(ioe.getMessage());
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch(InterruptedException ie){
            logger.severe("Connection got interrupted!!");
            ie.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

2) I traced the exception and I got it here: (Smack's source)

At the line - `HostAddress hostAddress = DNSUtil.getDNSResolver().lookupHostAddress(config.host, config.port, failedAddresses, config.getDnssecMode());`

```
// AbstractXMPPConnection.java
protected List<HostAddress> populateHostAddresses() {
        List<HostAddress> failedAddresses = new LinkedList<>();
        if (config.hostAddress != null) {
            hostAddresses = new ArrayList<>(1);
            HostAddress hostAddress = new HostAddress(config.port, config.hostAddress);
            hostAddresses.add(hostAddress);
        }
        else if (config.host != null) {
            hostAddresses = new ArrayList<HostAddress>(1);
            HostAddress hostAddress = DNSUtil.getDNSResolver().lookupHostAddress(config.host, config.port, failedAddresses, config.getDnssecMode());
            if (hostAddress != null) {
                hostAddresses.add(hostAddress);
            }
        } else {
            // N.B.: Important to use config.serviceName and not AbstractXMPPConnection.serviceName
            hostAddresses = DNSUtil.resolveXMPPServiceDomain(config.getXMPPServiceDomain().toString(), failedAddresses, config.getDnssecMode());
        }
        // Either the populated host addresses are not empty *or* there must be at least one failed address.
        assert(!hostAddresses.isEmpty() || !failedAddresses.isEmpty());
        return failedAddresses;
    }
```

The exception is **NullPointerException** and I found that `getDNSResolver()` returns null. Of all the sources I have referenced, there wasn't anything related to DNS resolver as it is supposed to be internally handled by Smack. So my question is, have I missed out some crucial configuration or step in making the connection?

**EDIT:** I asked here because Smack is vast lib and there might some config someone knows that I might have missed. I am unable to set DNSResolver directly

Comment: @MartinW : I asked here because Smack is vast lib and there might some config someone knows that I might have missed. I am unable to set DNSResolver directly.

Comment: So the actually problem isn't the NPE, it's is that you need help configuring a library properly. Try asking about that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### **EDIT : ANSWER UPDATE**

**This is NOT a bug in Smack's source** as their Upgrade Guide for 4.2.0 explicitly mentions:

> **
>
> ### API Changes
>
> **
>
> **Warning**: This list may not be complete
>
> Introduced `ConnectionConfiguration.setHostAddress(InetAddress)`
>
> In previous versions of Smack,
>   `ConnectionConfiguration.setHost(String)` could be used to set the
>   XMPP service's host IP address. This is no longer possible due to the
>   added DNSSEC support. You have to use the new connection configuration
>   `ConnectionConfiguration.setHostAddress(InetAddress)` instead.

---

<s>*This seems to be a bug because*</s> I solved it by providing the Host Address (which was supposed to be inferred from {Host, Domain}). So, how did I know to provide the host address?

The trick lies here: (Smack' source)

```
// AbstractXMPPConnection.java

if (config.hostAddress != null) {
            hostAddresses = new ArrayList<>(1);
            HostAddress hostAddress = new HostAddress(config.port, config.hostAddress);
            hostAddresses.add(hostAddress);
        }
        else if (config.host != null) {
            hostAddresses = new ArrayList<HostAddress>(1);
            HostAddress hostAddress = DNSUtil.getDNSResolver().lookupHostAddress(config.host, config.port, failedAddresses, config.getDnssecMode());
            if (hostAddress != null) {
                hostAddresses.add(hostAddress);
            }
        } else {
            // N.B.: Important to use config.serviceName and not AbstractXMPPConnection.serviceName
            hostAddresses = DNSUtil.resolveXMPPServiceDomain(config.getXMPPServiceDomain().toString(), failedAddresses, config.getDnssecMode());
        }
```

You can see the if, else-if blocks here and since the exception arises in the `else if (config.host != null)` block, I provided hostAddress so that it never enters that block and it worked.

I know this is sort of a hack around the actual problem but this seems to be a bug in Smack 4.2.0 unless someone disproves me otherwise.

Bonus info: If after rectifying this problem, you get another exception in Base 64 encoding during login, refer to this - [XMPP client using Smack 4.1 giving NullPointerException during login](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29046171/xmpp-client-using-smack-4-1-giving-nullpointerexception-during-login)

Answer (score 4):

Not sure in 4.2.0 but in 4.2.2 (and newer), you will need smack-resolver-dnsjava-4.2.2.jar to be in your classpath, smack calls DNSUtil which is included in the package, if the class doesn't exist it returns NullPointerException.

Hope this help!
David

Comment: for a long time I iwas expecting to find this error. thanks

implementation 'org.igniterealtime.smack:smack-resolver-dnsjava:4.2.3'